Function that is discontinuous at $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...$ but continuous everywhere else
I'm working through Spivak's Calculus and one of the problem asks us to find a function $f$ that is discontinuous at $1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...$ but continuous everywhere else. Since the Thomae function is discontinuous at all rationals between 0 and 1 but continuous at every other point, I thought of making this slight modification to it:
$$f(x) =    \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      x & x = \frac{1}{n} ;n\in\mathbb{N} \\
      0 & else
\end{array} 
\right. $$
The next question was the same as the previous except the function must also be discontinuous at 0. So:
$$f(x) =    \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      5 & x = 0\\
      x & x = \frac{1}{n} ;n\in\mathbb{N} \\
      0 & else
\end{array} 
\right. $$
This is easy enough but Spivak chooses two answers that seem more than necessary that I was wondering if my solutions were correct. Here is what's given in the solution's manual:
$$f(x) =    \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & x \leq 0\\
      \frac{1}{floor\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} & 0 < x \leq 1 \\
      2 & x > 1
\end{array} 
\right. $$
$$f(x) =    \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      -1 & x \leq 0\\
      \frac{1}{floor\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)} & 0 < x \leq 1 \\
      2 & x > 1
\end{array} 
\right. $$

I cannot see anything wrong with your functions.

Spivac's functions are (weakly) increasing and have one-sided limits at the discontinuity points, but those properties weren't asked for.

His functions arise naturally if you’ve done Exercises 4.17 and 5.27. For example, in my 15 times teaching a course out of Spivak, I typically assigned all three exercises.
